# OpenNETCF 1.4 Vs OpenNETCF 2.3

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf

I have a chance to upgrade a legacy suite of applications currently using .net 1.1 to the newest .net framework.

It uses OpenNETCF 1.4 to communicate with the mobile device.

Is it worthwhile to upgrade from opennetCF ver 1.4 to ver 2.3 as well?

Should I be expecting significant roadblocks/issues while doing so

OR

if anyone has already done the upgrade, is it painless and beneficial?

The application utilizes Rapi from the OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication

The PDA applications run on Dell X51 and HP IPaQ series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It highly depends on what parts of the SDF you are using.  The RAPI stuff isn't part of the SDF at all, so it's not part of the communication equation.

SDF 1.4 was targeted for CF 1.0.  A whole lot of it got deprecated by CF 2.0 and 3.5 and most of those deprecated pieces we took out becasue there was no point in having functional duplications.

We also renamed a lot of things to be more in-line with general .NET naming conventions.

SDF 2.3 has a whole load of bug fixes over 1.4 as well.

So, in general, the migration from 1.4 to 2.3 consists mostly of:

- namespace changes to use System.* where the CF brought in capabilities only the SDF originally provided
- class name changes for renamed classes (classes that ended with a "2" were renamed to end with an "Ex".
- changes to code using refactored SDF pieces (the WiFi network stuff changed dramatically over that period)

Comment: Chris,

Thank you for your response. This is really what I looking for.

One time I had tried to replace OpenNETCF references with .Net 2.0 references, I had discovered that OpenNETCF controls had extra properties which .net controls did not, so it had ended up being more work than I had thought (TextDecoration?).